# Nonlinear second order ODE, first derivative missing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I have the following second order equation, where the first derivative is missing, and I am asked to find its solution:

$$x(t)''=-\omega^2x(t)+a(x(t))^2$$
I don't know how to solve it. I have tried with to substitute $f(x) = -\omega^2x(t)+a(x(t))^2 = v'$ and then set $x(t)' = v$ but it doesn't seem to help me...

Is my approach for this ODE wrong? Are there any other solution methods I could try out?

Would be thankful for any advice!

Comment: Do you know Laplace trasform ?

Comment: What are the specific expectations in the task of "find its solution"? Produce a plot, a numerical solution in some format, a symbolic solution, a perturbation approach?

Comment: Note that $x(t)=0$ is a solution.

Comment: For the perturbation method, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2201425/115115 and follow the links from the "Linked" side bar, recursing at least once.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I should‘ve been more specific on the exact task, sry! I‘m asked to „determine the dynamic behavior of the model“. Regarding the first question: No, sadly I‘m not familiar with laplace transform.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
 & x''=-\omega^2x+ax^2 \\
\cdot x'\implies & x'x''=-\omega^2xx' + ax^2x' \\
\int dt\implies & \frac{1}{2}x'^2=-\frac{\omega^2}{2}x^2 + \frac{a}{3}x^3 + C\\
\cdot2 \implies & x'^2=-\omega^2x^2 + \frac{2a}{3}x^3 + C \\
\text{solve for } x' \implies & \frac{x'}{\sqrt{\frac{2a}{3}x^3 -\omega^2x^2  + C}} = \pm 1
\end{align}
If you can integrate it, of course, you get a solution